# Side by side minipage and varwidth

Tags: minipage, width, varwidth

I'm looking for a way to combine the minipage and varwidth environments side by side, so that the width of minipage automatically adapts to that of varwidth, to fill the entire line.

```
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth-\varwidth}
Content of minipage.
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{varwidth}{.5\linewidth}
Content of varwidth.
\end{varwidth}
```

A two-step compilation may be required, but thanks for any suggestion. I don't know how to get the width of varwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### First possibility

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{doubleminipage}{+b}
 {
  \mbfore_doubleminipage:n { #1 }
 }{}

\seq_new:N \l__mbfore_doubleminipage_parts_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mbfore_doubleminipage:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__mbfore_doubleminipage_parts_seq { \BREAK } { #1 }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box
   {
    \begin{varwidth}{0.5\linewidth}
    \seq_item:Nn \l__mbfore_doubleminipage_parts_seq { 2 }
    \end{varwidth}
   }
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{\dim_eval:n { \linewidth - \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box - 1em }}
  \seq_item:Nn \l__mbfore_doubleminipage_parts_seq { 1 }
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{doubleminipage}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\BREAK
Some contents \\
on the right
\end{doubleminipage}

\end{document}
```

##### Second possibility

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{doubleminipage}{m}
 {
  \__mbfore_doubleminipage:n { #1 }
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{\dim_eval:n { \linewidth - \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box - 1em }}
 }
 {
  \end{minipage}\hfill\box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mbfore_doubleminipage:n
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box
   {
    \begin{varwidth}{0.5\linewidth}
    #1
    \end{varwidth}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{doubleminipage}{
  Some contents \\
  on the right
}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{doubleminipage}

\end{document}
```

##### Output for both

[image]

##### Note

I used a 1em gutter in order to separate the two boxes.

Comment: The first possibility seems better for my usage, but doesn't seem to produce the expected result.

Comment: @MB4E Sorry, but you’re not saying what is the result you expect.

Comment: The result is good for me, but the first possibility does not seem to work correctly and does not give the same result as the second one.

Comment: @MB4E Sorry, there was a typo, not sure how it crept in.

Comment: This is now working fine with current usage, even with `\begin{tcolorbox}[hbox] x \end{tcolorbox}` environments on the right side, but not with something like `\begin{tcblisting}{hbox,listing only} x \end{tcblisting}` or just `\begin{verbatim} x \end{verbatim}`. Is there a way to use verbatim content in the right side ? I had tried before and it is possible to put verbatim content in the varwidth environment.

Comment: @MB4E Verbatim would require a rather different approach.

Comment: Ok, new question here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/695710/56520.

Answer (score 1):

The `\MeasureVarwidth[<maximum width of varwidth>]{<text>}` command will measure the natural width of a `text` and save the content for later use.

If the measured content of `text` is greater than the optional `<maximum width of varwidth>` (default= `0.5\linewidth`), the width of the `varwidth` part  will be set to that value.

The width of the `minipage` will then be set to fill the entire line.

The minipages were enclosed in a `\fbox`  for better visualization.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % show the margins
                    
\usepackage{calc}% needed 
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newsavebox{\ToVarwidth}
\newlength{\WidthofVarwidth}
\newlength{\miniwidth} 


% save box and measure its width
\newcommand{\MeasureVarwidth}[2][0.5\linewidth]{% #1 optional max width of varwidth, #2 varwidth text
    \savebox{\ToVarwidth}{#2}%  
    \settowidth{\WidthofVarwidth}{\usebox{\ToVarwidth}}%
    \setlength{\miniwidth}{\linewidth-\WidthofVarwidth}%
    \ifdim\WidthofVarwidth>#1%
    \savebox{\ToVarwidth}{\parbox{#1}{#2}}%     
    \setlength{\miniwidth}{\linewidth-#1}%
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
    
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}% only for \fbox
    
\MeasureVarwidth{Some text}

\noindent\fbox{%% \fbox only to visualize 
    \begin{minipage}{\miniwidth} 
        Content of minipage.
    \end{minipage}%
            }\hfill
    \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
    \usebox{\ToVarwidth}
    \end{varwidth}

\bigskip

\MeasureVarwidth{Some text Some text Some text}

\noindent\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{\miniwidth}
        Content of minipage.
    \end{minipage}%
    }\hfill
    \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
        \usebox{\ToVarwidth}
    \end{varwidth}

\bigskip
\MeasureVarwidth{Some text   Some text  Some text Some text  Some text Some text Some text } 

\noindent\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{\miniwidth}
        Content of minipage.
    \end{minipage}%
}\hfill
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
    \usebox{\ToVarwidth}
\end{varwidth}

\bigskip

Changing the maximum width of \verb|varwidth| \medskip

\MeasureVarwidth[0.7\linewidth]{Some text    Some text  Some text Some text  Some text Some text Some text } 

\noindent\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{\miniwidth}
        Content of minipage.
    \end{minipage}%
}\hfill
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
    \usebox{\ToVarwidth}
\end{varwidth}  

\end{document}
```